# Code coverage for cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc, code-coverage, jenkins-plugins

[I am very much new to the visual studio environment. After working with visual studio for 2-3 days I was able to get some knowledge about it.]

Well. I am working in a testing team. I just wanna setup a code coverage for cpp code developed in visual studio 2010. There are merely 2 doubts I wanna ask

1.My company has purchased visual studio 2010 ultimate edition and using that I was able to generate the code coverage for a sample `test project (.dll)` created using `Test Project` template in visual studio.

> The problem here is that developers had written a test project using
>   cppunit as an `.exe`. So will I be able to get the code coverage for
>   an `.exe` too (with PROFILER enabled) using the usual method to get
>   the code coverage in visual studio ultimate edition. Or should I ask
>   them to write the unit tests using the Microsoft's unit test
>   framework(ie .dll). I just cant simply say do it, I need to present
>   them the genuine reason to do so.

2.The second thought I had was, there are lot more open source tools to get code coverage for cpp compiled using gcc or g++. So I thought of compiling the cpp code using g++ and use the open source tools to get code coverage. Is this a good idea?

> When I shared this idea with a senior developer he said there are lot
>   more cpp code designed to be MSDN specific, you cant do by this way.If
>   you wanna do so you should make the code cross platform compatible or
>   portable[something I couldn't understand].

So here is the final thing, I am trying to present them a immediate solution of getting code coverage using the visual studio ultimate edition which we have. And later on search for the best way to achieve this without purchasing any paid tools like ncover, squish coco, bullseye coverage, etc only so I opted for the above mentioned second option.
**My ultimate aim is to display the final report in the Jenkins so that everyone is able to see it without any manual intervention after the build process [which is not possible using the visual studio I guess,].**

There is a plugin called MSTestRunner plugin for jenkins which can generate unit tests report but not the coverage report.

I think I made it clear. If this is a duplicate question please mention me the link to.Thanks in advance

I forgot to say this I was also able to find some tool called vcxproj2cmake I think it is clear from the name itself. So if i use this tool to generate a cmake corresponding to the actual vcxproj will i be able to the my second choice?

**NOTE:**

> As for as now, I created a test project (lets say, **SampleTestProject**) as said in method 1 which has
>   only one test method (lest say, **TestMethod**) which in turn triggers all the unit tests written
>   using cppunit by the below mentioned method.
>
> > 1. I asked the devs to make the **`.exe`** (which they have already with cppunit unit tests written) as **`.dll`** in a specific format like it
> >        should contain a class called **`TestInitiator`** which contains the
> >        **`CppUnit::TextUI::TestRunner`** (the runner instance which triggers the
> >        cppunit tests, ideally this method should be present in order to trigger cppunit tests) with all the test methods defined in a suite.
> > 2. This method is called by the above mentioned **TestMethod** in the **SampleTestProject** and thereby obtaining the code coverage

By this way the code coverage was obtained with very less change done to the code.Hope you like it!

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot use GCC or G++ in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment bro, not in visual studio but as a separate way like through command line. I am saying this because the source code doesn't change right.

Comment: @enedil I am pretty sure you can. Visual Studio should be capable to use other Compilers and even if it is just through a plugin.

Comment: Any solutions to my questions?

Comment: It is possible to [build with Clang](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html) in Visual Studio. Clang does have some support for code coverage (it's got a `--coverage` flag), but I'm not sure what else you'd need to do to get it to work

Comment: Just as an FYI, newer versions of Visual Studio come with a new test runner which allow third parties to integrate into visual studio. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms253138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx . Disclaimer, I am employed by Microsoft